# If statement to continue appending data

Tags: python, if-statement

My code appends data from hundreds of webpages. Some of these webpages have no data. I need my code to move to the next page when there is no data to append on the webpage. When there is no data to append on the webpage 'venue' = the word 'null'.

My code:

```
for meet in range(5163022,5163024):
    request = requests.get(f'https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/{meet}',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json = request.json()
    venue = json['meet']['venueAbbr']
    for meet in json['raceCollection']:
        date = meet['date']
        raceno = meet['raceNumber']
        distance = meet['distance']
        racetime = meet['raceTime']
        data.append((date, venue, raceno, distance, racetime))
```

What should I use as an if statement and where should I place the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` to move to the next iteration of the loop.

```
for meet in range(5163022,5163024):
    request = requests.get(f'https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/{meet}',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json = request.json()
    venue = json['meet']['venueAbbr']
    if venue == 'null':
        continue
    for meet in json['raceCollection']:
        date = meet['date']
        raceno = meet['raceNumber']
        distance = meet['distance']
        racetime = meet['raceTime']
        data.append((date, venue, raceno, distance, racetime))
```

Comment: Still getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Post a full stacktrace. Are you sure `json['meet']` isn't returning `None` instead of the string `"null"`?

Comment: Here is a link to the API https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5163022. It says 'null' but I have tried using None as well in the if statement but that doesn't work either.